# warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking

Tags: c, gcc, openssl, компоновщик, warning

Здравствуйте. Программа на C всего лишь отсылает письмо через (E)SMTP с помощью OpenSSL. Компилируется вот так:

```
gcc -static -o test test.c `pkg-config --libs --static openssl`
```

При этом выдаются предупреждения:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_globallookup':
(.text+0x11): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(b_sock.o): In function `BIO_get_host_ip':
(.text+0x10d): warning: Using 'gethostbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(b_sock.o): In function `BIO_get_port':
(.text+0x2a2): warning: Using 'getservbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
```

Пробовал загружать на разные серверы и запускать, все работает, письмо приходит. Даже на LAMP-хостингах с cPanel (в этом случае запускал через CRON). Поэтому интересно, какие именно сложности все же могут возникнуть, и в чем вообще суть этой проблемы?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, `glibc` просто вообще не поддерживает статическую линковку. Именно об этом вас предупреждает компилятор (линкер). Т.е.  он говорит, что несмотря на `-static` он не сможет статически влинковать `glibc`. `glibc` все равно останется shared library.

Comment: Компилятор предупреждает о том, что при статической линковке библиотек программа будет корректно работать только с версией glibc, используемой при линковке. При отличии в версиях корректная работа не гарантируется.